# ¿Por qué escribimos "El abogado probó que su defendido 'era' inocente" y no 'sería'?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, cópulas

> El abogado probó que su defendido sería/era/había sido/había estado inocente.

La frase es de Josefa Martin Garcia.
No entiendo por qué usa **era** en vez de **sería**.

¿Puede usar el pluscuamperfecto aquí?

Answer (score 3):

No tiene sentido usar el pretérito pluscuamperfecto (había sido). Eso significaría que el abogado intentaba demostrar que su cliente "había sido inocente pero ya no lo era"? Uno, de cara a la justicia, o es inocente o no lo es.

El tiempo verbal que tienes que usar, dado que ya estás usando "el abogado **probó**, es el pretérito imperfecto.

> El abogado probó que su defendido **era** inocente.

Con "inocente" se usa **ser** y no **estar**.

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede usar, pero tiene significado diferente.

Lo primero, `ser` o `estar`. `Ser` se utiliza cuando el sujeto se puede identificar con el atributo y puedes definir al sujeto por el atributo. Es una característica constante en la persona.

Por ejemplo:

> Yo soy inglés.

Siempre seré inglés y a mi se me puede identificar como inglés.

Por otro lado `estar` es una situación temporal a una característica temporal de la persona.

> Hoy estoy cansado

Hoy, y solamente hoy, estoy cansado y es posible que sea una persona que generalmente tiene mucha energía.

En tu caso, la característica es ser inocente. Si es algo temporal sería "estaba considerado inocente".

En cuanto los tiempos:

El pretérito imperfecto es usado refiriéndose a una acción pasada con relación a la otra acción. Se usa cuando la acción se produce simultáneamente a la acción pasada. Es decir, son acciones muy próximas en el tiempo.

Enfatizando este ejemplo yo pondría:

```
 El abogado probó AYER que su defendido era inocente
```

El pluscuamperfecto se refiere a una acción muy anterior a la acción descrita en la frase. En tu ejemplo y cambiándolo radicalmente un poco.

```
 El abogado probó que Napoleón había sido inocente en realidad
```

Incluso en esta frase el imperfecto tendría sentido, como ves, para usar el pluscuamperfecto cambias el significado de la frase, enfatizando un poco el tiempo pasado.

Comment: Esta regla es una guía util, pero no siempre es verdad: Decimos "Estoy muerto" no "Soy muerto" aún cuando es algo relativamente definitivo.

Comment: Es la regla general, aunque la he descrito simplificada. Hay excepciones, como alguien que dice que está casado que no está pensando en divorciarse o quien dice que es francés y puede que piense cambiarse de nacionalidad en breve

Answer (score 0):

El defendido es inocente y el abogado lo probó.  Es como si usaras el estilo indirecto.  El tiempo presente (es) se convierte en el tiempo pretérito imperfecto (era).